# Does Ansible have a module for forking a github repo?

Tags: github, ansible, fork

We have a project which requires a github repo to be forked.
Can Ansible do this? (I looked through the docs and google searched it and found nothing).

Is the best option using the github API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) can execute any command you want on a remote host through an SSH session.

That means you can use any API or even simple script you want to fork/clone your project.
If you can achieve that through git commands in a script, you can make Ansible execute that same script.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your title question: **no**, Ansible does not currently have a *module* specifically for git that does forking. You can use the shell and command module (which are not idempotent).

The only modules for git commands are [git](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html) and [git_config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_config_module.html).

With the git module you can create and switch to a branch using the *version* parameter if that scratches your itch.
i.e.

```
- git:
    repo: 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git'
    dest: /path/to/repo
    version: test-branch
```